# Laravel: How to rollback a listener if other catch exception?

Tags: laravel, exception, events, listener

There is an event with four listeners. The listeners are doing some financial tasks, hence if one fails, all previous listeners must rollback to verify the consistency of the entire system. How can I do this?

When tasks are among functions I can do this as follows:

```
f1();

function f1(){
    try{
        DB:BeginTransaction();
        //do the tasks
        DB::commit();
        f2();
    }catch(\Throwable $t){
        DB::rollback();
    }
}
function f2(){
    try{
        DB:BeginTransaction();
        //do the tasks
        DB::commit();
        f3();
    }catch(\Throwable $t){
        DB::rollback();
        throw $t;
    }    
}
function f3(){
    try{
        DB:BeginTransaction();
        //do the tasks
        DB::commit();
    }catch(\Throwable $t){
        DB::rollback();
        throw $t;
    }    
}
```

As you see when a function, say `f3()` encounters an exception, it rollbacks and throw new exception. Hence the calling line in function `f2()` encounters exception and it also rollbacks and it again throws the exception and It causes the calling line in function `f1()` encounters exception and rollbacks again. Therefore this chain of `throw` in catch verifies all database inserts in previous functions are rollback.

But in case of Listeners I don't know how to handle this.

Answer (score -1):

You're doing separate transactions for each function, so they're independant. `f3()` can't rollback `f1()` because you're commiting it before `f2` and  `f3` are called.

However, you could do it like this:

```php
DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    f1();
    f2();
    f3();
    DB::commit();
} catch (/* your exceptions here */) { // QueryException is a good one to catch
    DB::rollBack();
} catch (\Exception $e) { // add generic Exception for good measure
    DB::rollBack();
}
```

where `f1`, `f2` and `f3` are just the tasks.

```php
function f1() {
    // f1 tasks
}

function f2() {
    // f2 tasks
}

function f3() {
    // f3 tasks
}
```

Or just call `commit` AFTER everything is done.

```
f2();
DB::commit();
...

f3();
DB::commit();
```

As for event listeners... I'm not sure but maybe chaining them while passing in the connection instance (`$connection = DB::getConnection();` nad  then using it to make queries. `$connection->query()->.....` ) could work.

There is some information in the documentation about using (queued) listeners inside a transaction here

https://laravel.com/docs/queues#jobs-and-database-transactions

Comment: My method works. I was asking about listerners